# Создание аналога gksu для Qt 4

Tags: linux, qt, qt4

Как запустить графическое приложение под другим пользователем, в частности, под root? Без использования fly, gksu и т.п.

Поясню задачу:
мы залогинены под обычным пользователем (не sudoer) user. Запускаем наше свеженаписанное приложение X под своим же пользователем. Открывается форма, аналогично fly и иже с ними. Вводим логин root`a (или другого пользователя) и его пароль. Если логин-пароль верны, запускается какое-то нужное нам приложение именно из-под root (или другого указанного пользователя). Через консоль мы не вводим никаких паролей, аналогично fly, gksu, kdesu, synaptic и т.д.

Пока нашел такие варианты:
1)владелец приложения Х - root, установлен setuserid. Введенные данные в графической форме проверяются на соответствие системным логину-паролю пользователя, т.к. владелец root - прав достаточно для этого. Затем, если "авторизация" прошла, выполняется запуск нужного приложения. Один из недостатков - пользователь строго root. 
2)через sudoers, но это тоже совсем не подходит. каждый раз нужно добавлять нового пользователя в sudoers. 
Необходимо, чтобы приложение работало без предварительных танцев с бубнами, под любым пользователем, который знает пароль рута (или другого пользователя) и сможет его ввести в форму.

Оба варианта не подходят для решения задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Qt к этому никакого отношения не имеет.

1. `sudo -u USER myprogram` (чтобы избежать запроса пароля нужно чтобы юзер, который запускает программу, присутствовал как "беспарольный" в [sudoers](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sudoers&category=5&russian=0), ну, или в общем случае - имел права на запуск приложений от другого юзера)
2. man [setuid](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=setuid&category=2&russian=) (вызывать из приложения)

Comment: Нужно именно запрашивать пароль рута через форму, аналогично fly и gksu.

Comment: Так возьмите исходники gksu и посмотрите как там сделано. В любом случае Qt здесь никаким боком.

Comment: P.S. Беглый взгляд показал, что там всё равно примерно то же самое, что я и написал: пляски вокруг `/bin/su`  с введёнными в форме юзером/паролем.

Comment: Спасибо! С локальной машины ок, по ssh выдает ошибку: cannot connect to X server localhost

Comment: С sudoers`ами вариант не подходит.